# Magento 2.0 After migration Exisiting Customers can't log in

Tags: magento2, customer, login, magento2-migration-tool

I am facing a very awkward scenario. I have successfully migrated settings, data and delta from Magento 1.9.2.2 to Magento 2.0.2. Now all the products and the admin sales records, customers records are in there.

Now when i try to log in from the existing customer the page just refreshes and nothing happens. If i make a new account and login from that it will act normally.

Why it is happening?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have to set your encryption key from app/etc/local.XML to your data-migration-tool  folders m1version/config.XML <encrypt> tag at migration time

Comment: that is already there.  the tag in config xml is crypt_key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment the **"settings step"** in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/version/config.xml

```
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <!--<step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>-->
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
```